# How can I set the alpha value of lines connecting only certain points in my plotly.js scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, scatter-plot, opacity, plotly.js

I posted this question over at the Plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-i-set-the-alpha-value-of-lines-connecting-only-certain-points-in-my-plotly-js-scatter-chart/77810. But I'm also posting it here since I rarely get responses over there.

I have a scatter plot using plotly.js. I'm wondering if there's a way to set the alpha value of only certain lines connecting the data points. For example, in this graph here:

[image]

...I have drawn the lines connecting Aug 10 to Aug 11 and Aug 11 to Aug 12 with an opacity of about 0.3. But this was in MS Paint so that I can illustrate it here. Is there a way to do this in plotly.js?

Thanks!